Logs not being written of parent directory included in filename
Updated with new code
I have a have a main notebook in databricks that is run which creates the root logger in the main notebook, imports the configuration from a logger.py and calls other modules which contain other loggers:
# main notebook

import logging
from logger import get_logfile_name, configure_logger

NAME = 'job1'

from logger import (
    configure_logger,
    get_logfile_name, 
)

# Set up root logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logfile = get_logfile_name(NAME)
logger = configure_logger(logger, logfile=logfile)

import os
import logging
from dates import get_current_date
from source import project_log_dir


def get_logfile_name(name):
    # Get current date to append to file name
    formatted_date = get_current_date()
    logfile = f"{name}/{name}_{formatted_date}.log"
    return logfile


def configure_logger(logger, logfile, level=logging.DEBUG):
    logger.setLevel(level)

    logfile_output = os.path.join(project_log_dir, logfile)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(logfile_output), exist_ok=True)

    if logfile:
        # Create a file handler with detailed formatting for log output
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile_output, mode="a")
        fformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(fformatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    # Create a stream handler with simple formatting for cell output
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    sformatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    stream_handler.setFormatter(sformatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    # Remove random Pyspark logs
    logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    if logfile:
        logger.info(f'Logger initiated. Logs will be written to {logfile_output}')
    else:
        logger.info('Logger initiated.')

    return logger

# other modules
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


The output looks fine when running the notebook but there aren't any files being written. I've experimented with different ways and this seems to be the correct way to manage different loggers that write to the same file logfile.log. The issue is it isn't writing the logs and not sure why.


Any reason why you're running pure python code (not PySpark) on Spark/Databricks cluster? IMO there are 2 ways to go: 1. Write pyspark code, run it on Spark/Databricks cluster, and log using log4j2. 2. Write pure python code, use python logging and run this code elsewhere (not a Spark/Databricks cluster). With a Databricks cluster, you have to understand security/distribution/file-system etc. to write to a log file.

Great question. The reason is that I was working on a project for another team. Most of that team isn't too familiar with Pyspark so I needed to transfer the code to Python so they could continue using it.

Return the file_handler along with the logger.
def get_logger(....)


return logger,file_handler


Calling Notebook
logger,file_handler = get_logger(...)

In the last cell of the calling notebook add this line
file_handler.close()
logger.removeHandler(file_handler)

Now you will notice the log file in the same folder as the notebook.


Thanks! Added this and now its getting a file not found error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Workspace/.../logfile.log' File <command-3660103723983015>, line 11       9 logger = logging.getLogger()      10 logfile = get_logfile_name(NAME) ---> 11 logger, file_handler = configure_logger(logger, logfile=logfile) File /usr/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py:1201, in FileHandler._open(self)
which is weird because the folder exists and worked fine right before.

The get_logger function is not part of Notebook? Is it in a .py file?
if logfile:
try:
open(logfile, 'a').close()
except OSError as e:
print("Failed creating the file - {e}")

I removed the get_logger() function and just create the root logger in the notebook: logger = logging.get_logger(), then use the function above to configure it. But sometimes it works and sometimes I get that error above. Not sure why.

apologies for the off-topic question - but are we able to write log files into dbfs using logging ? I got an error stating that random writes were not supported - so had to write to /tmp path and then move it to an ADLS mount...is this not true anymore ? because we have had issues when the cluster just dies and we lose the file written to the /tmp path..

@rainingdistros can you please post it separately with sample code, cluster details, (uc / non uc)

This worked. Thanks!
